# Linux - Any way to configure or create a script/program to make right click not select menu item?

Tags: linux, menu, patch, right-click

The default behavior for right-clicking on most recent Linux distros is to select a menu item in a right-click menu upon releasing the right mouse button. While this saves some mouse presses, it is driving some of my Windows-trained (and rather vocal) coworkers completely bonkers, and a lot of searching has told me that there is no option to change this behavior in the distros they are using (mostly RHEL 6).

To make my work environment a little less volatile I would like to try to program a fix or patch for their systems to make right clicking work like they are used to (the menu does not even appear until the right mouse button is released), but I don't know what kinds of tutorials I should be looking for (shell scripts? C? etc.) in order to do this.

If I could be pointed in the right direction that would be lovely! (or if someone by chance already knows of a fix, that would work too, though a lot of Googling has told me that there does not appear to be one currently)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20550/how-to-disable-the-forward-back-buttons-on-my-mouse

But instead of disabling the forward and back buttons, disable the right click mouse button. You can easily dump the resulting command into a shell script which calls xmodmap. Then you can make icons that disable and enable the right mouse button, for the times where they will need it.